# Generate all possible dictionary combinations given number of steps?

Tags: python

Assume:

only 4 letters (a, b, c, d) are used

Say I have a dictionary comprise of occurrences(>=0) of the 4 letters

```
d = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":1, "d":3}
```

and I am given a "steps" number.

I want to find all the dictionaries that are possible given a "steps" number of occurrence subtractions.

For example

```
# given the above dictionary and a steps of 2
moo = {"a":1, "b":1, "c":1, "d":2}
# moo is a possibility because I simply took away 1 b and 1 d
# how do I find all the possibilities? (note: occurrences cannot be negative)
```

edit: steps as in exactly 2 steps

Note: I want to find all the "moo"s, or all the dictionaries that are possible given a reference dictionary and a number of steps.  I don't care about testing if two dictionaries meet the steps requirement.

I think I came up with some recursive code to solve this problem:

```
def genDict(d, steps):
    if steps == 0:
        return [d]
    dList = []
    for key, value in d.items():
        if value > 0:
            temp = dict(d)
            temp[key] = value -1
            dList += genDict(temp, steps-1)
    return dList
```

Anyone got a non-recursive solution that won't hog up memory?

Comment: Exactly two "steps" or up to two "steps"?

Comment: @TimPietzcker sorry I meant exactly 2 steps

Comment: I suggest you read Peter Norvig's Python spelling corrector.  It includes code to compute "edit distance" and maybe you can get some useful ideas from it.  If your dictionaries always use single letters as keys, then you could encode your dictionaries as strings and maybe just use the code from this!  http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Answer (score 2):

It do't use many memory, because it change the same list in the recursion, however if you want to collect the result instead of just print it, you need to append a deepcopy of d to the result list.

```
d = map(list, {"a":1, "b":2, "c":1, "d":3}.items())
step = 2
def choose(d, pos, step):
    if step == 0:
        print d
        return
    if d[pos][1] > 0:
        d[pos][1] -= 1
        choose(d, pos, step-1)
        d[pos][1] += 1
    if pos < len(d)-1:
        choose(d, pos+1, step)
choose(d, 0, 2)
```

This output:

```
[['a', 0], ['c', 0], ['b', 2], ['d', 3]]
[['a', 0], ['c', 1], ['b', 1], ['d', 3]]
[['a', 0], ['c', 1], ['b', 2], ['d', 2]]
[['a', 1], ['c', 0], ['b', 1], ['d', 3]]
[['a', 1], ['c', 0], ['b', 2], ['d', 2]]
[['a', 1], ['c', 1], ['b', 0], ['d', 3]]
[['a', 1], ['c', 1], ['b', 1], ['d', 2]]
[['a', 1], ['c', 1], ['b', 2], ['d', 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly...

1. Get the complete string from the dictionary.

   ```
   d = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":1, "d":3}
   my_string = ""
   for key, value in d.iteritems():
       my_string += key * value
   # my_string now contains 1 a, 2 b's, 1 c, and 3 d's.
   ```
2. Use [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to get all possible permutations of the string.

   ```
   from itertools import permutations
   for i in permutations(my_string):
       print i # Do something meaningful with the output
   ```

Comment: You need to include the deleted strings as well. `permutations(my_string, len(my_string)-j) for j in xrange(steps)`